# Capturing photo , audio and video from web application

Tags: javascript, android, ios, jquery-mobile, extjs

I am making a web application which has the functionality of capturing the photo, audio and video. Till now i have considered the JQM and Sencha framework.
For photo i am able to directly open a camera using Sencha and it works great. But for audio and video i am not able to find solution like photo. Does anyone has done this? or have an idea how can this done?. 
I am aware this can be done via Phone-gap but that is for the Hybrid App (native + html5) app i want to do it for browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in html 5 that will allow you to acces the camera/microphone directly in iOS.
Since iOS 6 there is only the option the upload an photo via the `input` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.getUserMedia).

Supports is still sparse though - see [here](http://caniuse.com/stream)
Tutorial - see [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/?redirect_from_locale=fr)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using Media element. I've built entire JQM mobile solutions using the video player capabaility, and audio.

http://mediaelementjs.com/